# Adding the difference of two dates to another date, avoiding leap year

Tags: c#, date, datetime

My goal is to figure out the difference between two dates and then add that amount of days to the original start.

```
DateTime originalStart = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime newDate = originalStart.AddDays((endDate - startDate).TotalDays);
```

**For example with the following params:**
original start: 1/1/2015
start date: 1/1/2016
end date: 1/1/2017

**newDate should be:** 1/1/2016 (difference between start and end is 1 year so then we add that one year to original start)

My problem is that if a leap year is part of the date difference between endDate and startDate and then I go and add those days to originalStart. I end up with dates like 1/2/2016 for newDate.

Any idea how I can avoid leap years here to make sure if the difference between 1/1/2016 and 1/1/2017 is rounded. I would only like to add exactly one year to originalStart and not the extra day because of the leap year.

Comment: [Just check if the year is a leap year and take action appropriately](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isleapyear(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: First check if any of the start or end years are leap years or not. Then check if February 29 is in your target time frame. If so, substract one day.

Comment: What means "avoiding lear year" at all? What is the desired result if the  timespan overlapped two leap years but if you add this timespan to originalStart you only overlap one leap year?

Comment: What if the dates are 4/1/2016 and 5/1/2016.  Should that result in 1/31/2015 (which you current solution does) or since it's exactly one month difference should it actually be 2/1/2015?

Comment: @juharr if it is exactly one month difference it should be 2/1/2015.

Comment: The problem is that you're expecting "human" results from math operations. There's always like to be edge cases. The most obvious one is - if you compute the difference between `2016-02-28` and `2016-02-29` and then apply that to `2017-02-28`, what should the result be?

Comment: @BlakeRivell In that case you'll need to handle more than leap years since neither months nor years are a standard measurement of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DateTime originalStart = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
    DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2016, 1,1);
    endDate .Dump();
    DateTime startDate= new DateTime(2017, 1,1);
    startDate.Dump();

    TimeSpan span = startDate- endDate ;

    // because we start at year 1 for the Gregorian 
    // calendar, we must subtract a year here.

    int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1;
    int months = (zeroTime + span).Month - 1;
    int days = (zeroTime + span).Day;

    years.Dump();
    months.Dump();
    days.Dump();
originalStart= originalStart.AddMonths(months);
originalStart = originalStart.AddYears(years);
originalStart = originalStart.AddDays(days);
```

Comment: I do not have access to.Dump() what is it?

Comment: @BlakeRivell This was likely created in LinqPad that uses `Dump` for writing objects to a console.  So you could just replace them with `Console.WriteLine` calls.

Comment: I assume you meant `AddYears(years)` and not `AddYears(days)`.